# how to deploy the smart contract in brownie

Tags: addresses, python, network, brownie, time

```
Error:  Final argument must be a dict of transaction parameters that includes a `from` field specifying the address to deploy from
Terminating local RPC client...
```

smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Timelock{
     //who can withdraw?
     //how much?
     //when?
     address payable benefciary;
     uint256 releaseTime;

    constructor(address payable _benefciary,uint256 _releaseTime)public payable{
    require(_releaseTime >= block.timestamp);
      benefciary = _benefciary;
      releaseTime = _releaseTime;
    }

    function release() public payable{
        require(block.timestamp >= releaseTime);
        address(benefciary).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

}
```

deploy scripts:

```
from brownie import network, config, accounts
from brownie import TimesLock

def get_account():
    if network.show_active() == "development":
        return accounts[0]
    else:
        return accounts.add(config['wallets']['from_key'])

def deploy_fund_me():
    account = get_account()
    times_lock = TimesLock.deploy({"from": account},"block.timestamp")
    print(f"contract deployed to {times_lock.address}")



def main():
    deploy_fund_me()
```

Comment: Hi, please add a minimalistic question. Right now, you posting everything here is just someone debugging your issues. Looking at it quickly, your private key is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you first have to pass the arguments into `TimesLock.deploy`
and then last the dictionary `{"from": account}`.

So maybe something like:

```
times_lock = TimesLock.deploy(_beneficiary, _releaseTime, {"from": account})
```

Answer (score 0):

The [deploy function](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core-contracts.html?highlight=deploy#deploying-contracts) should be called with the contract constructor arguments(if any) and the "from" field dict. so in your case, it should be something like :

```
times_lock = `TimesLock.deploy('<benificery_address>','<release_time>',{"from": account})`
```